# Is there a function in R to count the number of a specific character within a word in a given string?

Tags: r, stringr

Is there a function in R to count the number of a specific character within a word in a given string?
Such as, to count the number of "a"s that occur in each word and arrange them to find the word with the highest number of "a"s, in this case "Banana".
x <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Pear")

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R you can use

```
x[which.max(lengths(gregexpr("a",tolower(x))))]
[1] "Banana"
```